# How to do horizontal scrolling,vertical scrolling and tab box textview horizontal scrolling in an activity

Tags: android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, android-tablelayout, vertical-scrolling

I am facing some problem in designing one screen in which vertical page scrolling, horizontal page scrolling and tab box textview horizontal scrolling work(if textView bigger than box).

I have attach a required image. please give me some idea, so that i can design this screen.

See required design:

[image: (click to see required design)]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Sr. no"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Name owner address"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Sizes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="BHkk"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Call et.c."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/dummyText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="New Text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="New Text" />

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Brother, are you trying to say with using horizontal scrollview, i can do all the things which mention in required design ?Then what about vertical scrolling and text scrolling...how do i achieve this text scrolling

Comment: now it is working both way, check out above code, ask if you still unsatisfied, otherwise vote my answer, thanks for reply

Comment: thanks for your reply, i vote you but stack says, i cannot vote you, because of less than 15 reputation.

Comment: hahaha i am new here i don't know rule, did my code really help you?